# VB.NET - How to create Notification Popup window (from bottom)

Tags: vb.net

i want to show a form in the lower right of the taskbar but then when i use a dual monitor it just passes here is my code

```
Public Class BNotifyUI
Private Sub BNotifyUI_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Me.Visible = True
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
    y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height = Me.Height

    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False

    Do Until x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width = Me.Width
        x = x - 1
        Me.Location = New Point(x, y)


        'text visible here

    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub BNotifyUI_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseClick
    'Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: *"it just passes"*.  What does that even mean?  I haven't tested [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?351757) for a long time but you might find it useful.

Comment: Given that the descriptions of the VBA and VB.NET tags explicitly state not to use each for questions about the other, why have you used both tags?  When you spam tags, you waste the time of those people watching that tag.  Know what language you're using and only add relevant tags.

Comment: So you want it in the lower right of your 1st monitor, or second monitor?

Comment: `Do Until x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width = Me.Width` makes no sense at all.  What are you actually trying to achieve there?  You should start by turning `Option Strict On`, in both the project properties and the IDE options.  That would cause the compiler to flag that line as a problem.  It wouldn't fix it for you but at least it would alert you that there's an issue there.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - sorry for the tags, i'm new here.. and thanks for the link and tip will try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, Thanks for the tips guys ^_^

```
 Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
        y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height - 10

        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False

        Do Until x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width - 20
            x = x - 1
            Me.Location = New Point(x, y)


            'text visible here

        Loop
```